# Solve $y'' + 2y' + y = 4e^t - 4e^tu(t-1)$, where $u(t-1)$ is the unit step function at $1$, $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace, step-function

I need to solve $$y'' + 2y' + y = 4e^t - 4e^tu(t-1)$$where $u(t-1)$ is the unit step function at $1$, $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=0$

I used the Laplace transform and got

$$Y(s) = \frac{4}{(s-1)(s+1)^{2}} - \frac{4e^{1-s}}{(s-1)(s+1)^{2}}$$

then by the Inverse Laplace Transform,

$$y(t) = e^{t} - e^{-t} -2te^{-t} + (-e^{t} + e^{2-t} +2e^{2-t}(t-1))u(t-1)$$

is the answer correct?

Comment: Plug your answer into the differential equation and see if it works...

Comment: how do you differentiate the unit step function?

Comment: On its own, $u(t)$ behaves like a constant function, but with a jump discontinuity. Its derivative is zero everywhere except at the jump, where it doesn't exist. The product of $u(t)$ and a differentiable function $f(t)$ has the same derivative $f'(t)$ but defined on only part of the domain of $f$. So for example,$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}u(t)\sin(t)=\begin{cases}\cos(t)&\text{for }t>0\\0&\text{for }t<0\end{cases}=u(t)\cos(t)$$